# type and object class, which comes first?

Tags: python, python-3.x, metaclass

Below output shows that:

1. the `type` class is the meta-class of the `object` class.
2. the `object` class is the base class of the `type` class

```
    >>> object.__class__
    <class 'type'>
    >>>
    >>>
    >>> type.__bases__
    (<class 'object'>,)
```

From 1, it seems `type` class **creates** the `object` class so it must precede the `object` class.

From 2, it seems `object` class must exist before `type` class so `type` class can have something to inherit.

This looks like kind of a chicken-egg problem.

Anyone could shed some light on this? Thanks.

Some references:

[Python object instantiation and meta-class](https://www.honeybadger.io/blog/python-instantiation-metaclass/)

Comment: The relation between type and object is magic (i.e. "hardcoded" to be this way), you cannot implement this yourself in python. Both come first, both come second.

Comment: @timgeb I think I'm beginning to see the point of The Holy Trinity…

Comment: @timgeb ...like the first push by the God :)

Comment: @deceze took you a while. That's what you get for not being dutch.

Comment: @timgeb  I'll try harder to be Dutch next time…